# Left join with a select dependent on rows value

Tags: sql

I have a table, tableA

```
Foo  bar  matcher
a    b    456
c    d    123
e    f    789
…
```

And I have another very large table, tableB

```
Count matcher
1     123
2     456
2     123
...
```

From tableB I want to find details for a specific matcher

```
  count   matcher
  1       123
  2       123
```

But I just want to use the row with the maximum count

```
  count   matcher
  2       123
```

Then I wish to left join tableB onto tableA

```
  foo   bar   matcher   count
  a     b     456       10
  c     d     123       2
  e     f     789       5
  ...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: which database and version is this ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.Foo, a.bar, b.matcher, max(b.Count) Count
from tableB b
left join tableA a
on a.matcher = b.matcher
group by a.Foo, a.bar, b.matcher
```